# I want to convert datetime to unix timestamp in SQL Server 2005 and update table value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

Is this actually a correct query in terms of syntax:? I need to know if its valid first.
I hope you understand what I am trying to do.

So please let me know.

```
update userdata 
set totaltime = totaltime + (DATEDIFF(s, '19700101', GETDATE()) - logintime) 
where user= .....
```

`totaltime` and `longtime` columns are both in `userdata` table.

`totaltime` column is inserted like that too:

```
update userdata 
set totaltime = DATEDIFF(s, '19700101', GETDATE())
```

Basically I do this to convert datetime in SQL Server to unix timestamp for easier calculation, so is this all correct?

**Quick Explanation of what I want to do:**

I want to add ranking for most online users (like 1 day online, 2 days and etc), so upon logging to the system - it will update the column `LoginTime` with the current time when the user is logging and upon disconnecting - it should compare current time now on disconnecting and `LoginTime` and update the `TotalTime` with the additional online time. So, I believe what I want to do with unix timestamp is the best, right? In that way I can add online time to the total of the specific user easier, isn't that correct?

Comment: "for easier calculation" - at the SQL server end? Is that really necessary? The date processing functions are easy to use and quite comprehensive.

Comment: the field you add is `longtime` (as you write in your comment) or `logintime` (as you write in the code block)? anyway why do that? use native sql time function for all calculation: you get the result and the data is human readable.

Comment: I want to add ranking for most online users (like 1 day online, 2 days and etc), so upon logging to the system - it will update the column `LoginTime` with the current time when the user is logging and upon disconnecting - it should compare current time now on disconnecting and `LoginTime` and update the `TotalTime` with the additional online time. So, I believe what I want to do with unix timestamp is the best, right? In that way I can add online time to the total of the specific user easier, isn't that correct?